# QGIS point numeration

Tags: qgis, python

I am wondering if there was an easy way to assign id's to existing points, but not in a manual way and not consistenly.

For example i have this file which contains 2 points in one position: [image: Example]

I need the first point (and second but in the same position) to be numerated 1 and 80, then 2 and 79 and so on.

Comment: The algorithm description is not yet clear to me. Where does the number 80 come from? Does it always start a positions where there are two points at the same location? Are the two co-located points part of the same line or of two different lines?

Comment: @underdark In this picture there are 80 points. I just didnt screenshot the close-up. The points are generated by converting lines to points algorithm, then they are copied and pasted so two points at the both ends of the line.

Comment: Please **edit the question** in response to requests for clarification. As a new user please take the  [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). In it you'll see that your job is to write the best possible question. You accomplish this by improving the question in response to comments.

Comment: If the 80, 79 point serie is at the same position as the 1,2,3 serie, then you don't have to bother with them at first. Start looking for a way to assign IDs to the first set of points. Converting 1 in 80 and 2 in 79 will be a piece of cake once you have the IDs correct from 1 to n.

Comment: In the field calculator, you can create a new field (virtual or not) with `$id` to creete a unique counter of all features. If that does not feed your needs, please add more details what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start again:

---

1. Remove those copied points using the **Delete duplicate geometries** tool from the *Processing Toolbox*:

   ```
   QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector general tools > Delete duplicate geometries
   ```

---

2. Go to **Field Calculator** and create an `ID` field (or whatever name you want) and use the expression mentioned by [@AndreJ](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9159/andrej):

   ```
   $id + 1
   ```

   Feature ids start from 0 hence why we need to add `+ 1` if you want to start it from 1. **Save the edits**.

---

3. Select all points and save them in a new layer either from the menubar (make sure you check the *Save only selected features* option):

   ```
   Layer > Save As...
   ```

   Or from the *Processing Toolbox*:

   ```
   QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector general tools > Save selected features
   ```

---

4. Now for the newly saved layer, go to **Field Calculator** and create/update an `ID` field (or use a field with the same name as in the original layer). Then use an expression like:

   ```
   80 - $id
   ```

   Assuming the total number of points in your layer is 80.

---

5. **Save the edits**. And now select and copy all features in this layer, edit your original layer and paste the features. Now when you select a 'point' at the end of a line, you should see in your *Attribute Table* two points with their ordered ids (e.g. first point should have `1` and `80` etc).

Comment: Great answer, although i forgot to mention that in the picture there is two branches, so if starting from right to left, i need to stop numeration from going forwards and go sideways. For example numeration stops at the center point, then it goes to the upper branch, comes back to center, goes to the lower branch and then proceeds to numerate until the end of the line, after that it must come back to the starting point without adding branches points

Comment: @Paul - Interesting...so you don't want to numerate the branch points a second time?

Comment: Yes, when the line is going back to the start point from the end I dont

Comment: @Paul - Apologies for responding late, guess I missed it in my inbox message. Before _Step 4_, I would manually delete those branch points, save the edits then continue using the **Field Calculator**. You can decide if you should use the expression `80 - $id` or if you removed two branch points then `78 - $id`.